# I can not create data by neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I configure them in the following ways, but it cannot create data.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/

just like：

```
# curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "name" : "testAsset", "os" : "test", "id":1000000}' http://192.168.10.42:8080/Asset
```

and response the code 201,there is no any exceptions or errors, but I have never been able to query the data I just inserted.

Is there a switch where I haven't opened it?

here is my Repository：

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "Asset", path = "Asset")
public interface AssetRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Asset, Long> {
@Query("Match(node:" + GlobalInfo.NODE_ASSET + ") where node.name = {name} return node limit 1")
Asset isExist(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Entity:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Asset")
public class Asset {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private long id ;

    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

---------update----------

EntityGraphMapper.class

```
 if (id < 0) {
        nodeBuilder = compiler.newNode(id).addLabels(labels).setPrimaryIndex(primaryIndex);
        context.registerNewObject(id, entity);
    } else {
        nodeBuilder = compiler.existingNode(Long.valueOf(id.toString()));
        nodeBuilder.addLabels(labels).setPrimaryIndex(primaryIndex);
        removePreviousLabelsIfRequired(entity, classInfo, nodeBuilder);
    }
```

My id type is "long" not "Long"
the default value is 0 and null,

Comment: You're querying a property called `name` but you're creating a node with `firstName` and `lastName` properties; I don't see a `name` property.

Comment: oh that is offical example,my request is `# curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "name" : "testAsset",  "os" : "test", "id":1000000}' http://192.168.10.42:8080/Asset`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; rather, edit your question with these details. Very hard to read code etc in comments. And anyone else reading the question will benefit from proper edits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I will improve it next time.